# Replacing dynamic polymorhism with static polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, template, template-meta-programming, polymorphism, c++17

Motivated due to the fact, that the avr-g++ places the vtables in RAM, I wrote a replacement using static polymorphy.

Consider the following example:

```
volatile uint8_t x;

struct IX {
    virtual void f() const = 0;
//    virtual ~IX() = default; // need delete
};

struct A : public IX {
    const uint8_t v = 0;
    void f() const override {
        x = v;
    }
};

struct B : public IX {
    const uint8_t v = 1;
    void f() const override {
        x = v;
    }
};

struct C : public IX {
    const uint8_t v = 2;
    void f() const override {
        x = v;
    }
};

volatile uint8_t index = 2;

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    const std::array<const IX*, 3> cc{&a, &b, &c};

    cc[index]->f();

    while(true) {}
}
```

Here we have some types `A`, `B` and `C` implementing an interface `IX` and placing pointers in the array `cc`. Then we call the virtual function `f()` for a specific instance. (Using this on a small µC like the AVRs, there is a "waste" of RAM, since the vtables are placed in RAM and each object contains a vptr, and a performance penalty due to the indirect call of `f()`.

So I looked for an alternative solution in this case: the simplest way is to use an heterogenous container like `std::tuple` and write a switch-statement:

```
const std::tuple<A, B, C> t;

auto f = [](const auto& v) {
    v.f();
};

switch (index) {
case 0:
    f(std::get<0>(t));
    break;
case 1:
    f(std::get<1>(t));
    break;
case 2:
    f(std::get<2>(t));
    break;
default:
    assert(false);
    break;
}
```

This yields to optimale machine-code but it is an unflexible solution. So I wrote a metafunction to call `f()` for a specific element of the tuple:

```
const std::tuple<A, B, C> t;

Meta::visitAt(t, index, [](const auto& v){v.f();});
```

And the implementation looks like:

```
namespace Meta {
    namespace detail {
        template<uint8_t  N>
        struct visit {
            template<typename T, typename F>
            static void at(T& tuple, uint8_t index, const F& f) {
                if (index == (N - 1)) {
                    f(std::get<N - 1>(tuple));
                }
                else {
                    visit<N - 1>::at(tuple, index, f);
                }
            }

        };
        template<>
        struct visit<0> {
            template<typename T, typename F>
            static void at(T&, uint8_t , const F&) {
                assert(false);
            }
        };

        template<typename T, typename F, size_t... I>
        void all(const T& tuple, const F& f, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
            (f(std::get<I>(tuple)), ...);
        }

    }
    template<typename... T, typename F>
    void visitAt(const std::tuple<T...>& tuple, uint8_t index, const F& f) {
        detail::visit<sizeof...(T)>::at(tuple, index, f);
    }
    template<typename... T, typename F>
    void visitAt(std::tuple<T...>& tuple, uint8_t index, const F& f) {
        detail::visit<sizeof...(T)>::at(tuple, index, f);
    }
    template<typename... T, typename F>
    void visit(const std::tuple<T...>& tuple, const F& f) {
        detail::all(tuple, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(T)>{});
    }
}
```

This works very well in my scenarios, yet is obviously limited to static containers (like `std::tuple`). There is also a for-each-like iteration `Meta::visit()`.

My question is: are there any other drawbacks / limitations with this approach?

Are there any improvements?

Comment: static polymorphism means you use templates and ducktyping everywhere to propagate the type (and associated functions) down to where they are called.

Comment: Technically true `performance penalty due to the indirect call of f()` but in real life that penalty is insignificantly small and will be drowned out by other CPU activity. I challenge you to measure it.

Comment: drawbacks: You are trying to solve a problem that does not really exist.

Comment: @LokiAstari: the main penalty is the waste of RAM for small µC.

Comment: @wimalopaan the above code has size. How big is the above code? On small µC I don't expect you will have many objects running on the fly (a couple at a time). So if we look at the above example. The code will be generated for every version of the tuple. So unless the code is smaller than size of the tuple multiplied by the size of the pointer then you have failed.